# Не отображает добавленую информацию в базе данных

Tags: php, html, mysql

Показывает "new record successfully inserted... "  но в базе данных ничего не появляется, подскажите что нужно изменить/добавить. Я в етом новичек поетому не судите строго :)
P.S Внизу сама база данных в виде `<ol>` и при вводе новая информация также должна там отображатся

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
if(isset($_POST['make'], $_POST['fuel'], $_POST['engine'], $_POST['colour'] )){
$make = $_POST['make'];
$fuel = $_POST['fuel'];
$engine = $_POST['engine'];
$colour = $_POST['colour'];
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO cars(car_name) VALUES(:make)');
$stmt2 = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO cars(car_fuel) VALUES(:fuel)');
$stmt3 = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO cars(car_engineSize) VALUES(:engine)');
$stmt4 = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO cars(car_colour) VALUES(:colour)');
            $stmt->bindParam(':make',$make);
            $stmt2->bindParam(':fuel',$fuel);
            $stmt3->bindParam(':engine',$engine);
            $stmt4->bindParam(':colour',$colour);

            if($stmt || $stmt2|| $stmt3 || $stmt4->execute())
            {
                        $successMSG = "new record successfully inserted...";
                        //header("refresh;index.php");// redirects image view page after 5 seconds.
                        echo $successMSG;
            }
            else{
                        $errMSG = "error while inserting...";
                        echo $errMSG;
            }
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="POST">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Motor Vehicle Characteristics</legend>
            Make/Model:<br>
            <input type="text" name="make" placeholder="Car Make & Model" required>
            <br>Fuel:<br>
            <input type="text" name="fuel" placeholder="Fuel Type" required>
            <br>Engine Size:<br>
            <input type="number" step="0.1" name="engine" placeholder="Engine Size" required>
            <br>Car Colour:<br>
            <input type="text" name="colour" placeholder="Colour" required>
            <br><input type="submit" value="Add">
            </fieldset>




        </form>
        <?php


        include 'connection.php';
        $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT car_ID,car_name,car_fuel,car_engineSize,car_color FROM cars ORDER BY car_ID ASC');
    $stmt->execute();


    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
    {



                echo '<ol>';
            echo '<img src="images/car.png" id="ol_img" "alt="car">';
                echo '<h3>Database "motor_vehicles" displayed using PHP :</h3>';
        while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {


                    echo '<li>';
                    echo $row['car_name'].'. <b><span style="color:#ff4d4d">Fuel type:</span></b> '.$row['car_fuel'].'. <b><span style="color:#ff4d4d">Engine size:</span>  '.$row['car_engineSize'].' <b>Litres. <b><span style="color:#ff4d4d">Colour:</span> '.$row['car_color'].'.';

                    echo '</li>';
                }
                echo '</ol>';


        }

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: А это вы одну строку в базу так добавляете?

Comment: Да какбы пытаюсь

Comment: вам бы `insert into cars (name, fuel, engineSize, color) values (:name, :fuel, :endine, :color)` сделать вместо того что есть, тогда глядишь и заработало бы

Comment: `$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO cars(car_name,car_fuel,car_engineSize,car_colour) VALUES(:make,:fuel,:engine,:colour)');
$stmt->bindParam(':make',$make);
$stmt->bindParam(':fuel',$fuel);
$stmt->bindParam(':engine',$engine);
$stmt->bindParam(':colour',$colour);
if($stmt->execute())`

Comment: а показывается у вас там а-ля успех, т.к. выполняете вы только последний запрос, а все остальные непустые дескрипторы. так что при сравнении ИЛИ выражение всегда истинно

Comment: splash58 , Спасибо огромное :) Заработало